# How to handle express route callback with wagner

Tags: node.js, express

When I add this part of code: `return function(req, res) {` it not working as it should... Insede that code I tried to console log but I don't get return... If I put console log above that return I get message in console... It mean it is some problem with that part of code, but I don't know waht...
Anyone know what is issue?

I am using: express: 4.13.4

```
var express = require("express");
var status = require("http-status");

module.exports = function(wagner) {
    var api = express.Router();
    api.get("/category/id/:id", wagner.invoke(function(Category) {
        return function(req, res) {

            console.log("HERE");

            Category.findOne({_id: req.param.id}, function(error, category) {

                if(error) {
                    return res
                        .status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .json({error: error.toString()});
                }

                if(!category) {
                    return res
                            .status(status.NOT_FOUND)
                            .json({error: "Not found"});
                }

                res.json({category: category});
            });
        };
    }));
}
```

Comment: Try with 'req.params.id' instead of 'req.param.id'. If it is still not working, please run your code on node server and post the error message, that way we will know what might be the error.